# SSL Certificate unable to find, even though it's in the keystore

Tags: java, linux, ssl, certificate, keytool

I'm trying to add a self-signed certificate to my java keystore. When I list all the certificates, it's also there, so it must have been saved. However, when I try to make a request in my class, I still get the exception:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have tried to replace the certificate but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: its likely that you are not pointing to the correct java keystore path. how did u try to make request ?

Comment: I have a simple class with a HttpClient in order to make a POST request and my application is running on a WildFly instance. The path for JAVA_HOME is the same as where the keystore is located or is there another point where I have to determine the path?

Comment: Just a suggestion in case if you are executing the class from eclipse make sure the java path is correctly configured for the workspace.

Comment: I'm developing on my machine (Windows) and have exported the .war-file on another machine (Linux) where it runs on a WildFly. My IDE and the WildFly use the same java version but, sorry if this is a dumb question, can there be any differences that produce this problem?

edit: by the way I had no problem yesterday, so this certificate worked already but there have been updates today on the Linux machine. Could these be a problem that they have overwritten something etc.?

Comment: Definitely not and did you install the certificate to java keystore in the linux machine were your war file is deployed ?

Comment: Okay, I have found the problem, it was actually the wrong path, I changed the keystore in the jre path which is set on the WildFly but I had to change the keystore in another jdk path even though I do not understand why.

However, thank you very much for your help!!